# Google BigQuery with Google Drive source error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a problem when creating the BigQuery table by CSV file that storge on Google Drive. The old tables still working fine. I try to use the same file but change to the Upload option (instead of Google Drive), it is working without problem.

I have had this problem 5-7 days ago.

[image: Error message after click create table button]

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes, I still facing this issue.

Comment: Meanwille it seems this issue as been fix but I got the same issue with avro file format. I created a new ticket here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/312491151

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been raised in this issue tracker. We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/217842096) and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this Link.

As a workaround you can disable the Editors tab, and then try creating the table. This works fine.

Comment: After disabling the Editors tab, then it works!

I notice that https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ format is doesn't work. But the new editor doesn't allow to use open?id format.

Thank you